# Magento 2 Readiness Check

Tags: php, magento

I have PHP Version 7.0.21 and working Magento 2 installed memory_limit= 2000M.

**However i get Readiness Check error:** 
Your current PHP memory limit is 128M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more. I have already changed limit to 2000M

**And when i want to use SSH to do anything i get:**
Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. See [here](http://www.mcompany.be/info.php)

Any idea how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you changed the memory limit value in your php.ini file, and did you restart apache/nginx then?
2. If you did so, make sure you edited the ini file that php actually uses. You can locate the file by inserting `<?php phpinfo(); exit(); ?>` on top of your index.php and reading the output

Comment: I changed the memory trugh Plesk and then i uploaded file php.info to see if the changes and yes it shows 2000M and i i have restarted VPS but still nothing works.

Comment: You can try memory_limit = -1 in your php.ini, which means no memory limit. I guess this is not recommended for production environments. Did you also edit .htaccess in magento root? There goes the magento memory limit, which should, as I think, not be higher than the one in your php.ini

Comment: i have this on my .htacces  same as php.ini ############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 2000M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################

Comment: I remember I ran into the same problem when installing magento2, but I don't remember how I actually fixed it. I will check my settings and write another comment when I find out more.

Comment: LOL thx mate that would be great. I just dont get why Magento2 got so complicated

Comment: Ok, here's another guess: Magento2 can have different php.ini files, for me it looks like the readiness check function uses a different php.ini than your webserver. I found a comprehensive guide here: https://lampjs.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/fixing-magento-2-readiness-check-by-local-php-ini/

Answer (score 0):

please set your `memory_limit`=4000 in php.ini and then restart 
 apache and mysql services